# two different seekbars with different tasks

Tags: android, google-maps

I have one `SeekBar` which does specific task. I want to add another `SeekBar` with different task.

How can I put

```
seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
```

unique for each `SeekBar`. Now when I touch either seekbar it results same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple options:

1) The common practice is to use an anonymous class.  Like this:

```
curSlider.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                Log.d("slider","stop tracking");

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {


            }
        });
```

2) If you want to use `this`, you need to use some logic to figure out which `SeekBar` is being moved (using ids or object references).  Like:

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
    if (seekBar == mySeekBar1) {

    } else if (seekBar == mySeekBar2) {

    }

}
```

Comment: I dont know how to access seekbar.getId() inside onProgressChanged. doesnot working!

Comment: What is there error?  It sounds like you're perhaps trying to call getId() within the first example I gave, which you don't need to do.

It should work fine on the second example (NOT using anonymous classes)

Comment: I was trying to use seekbar.getId() and didnt work. but exactly  if (seekBar == mySeekBar1) worked.. thanks

Answer (score -2):

you can add any no. of seekbars and every one to do something
I have a sample code  with 3 seekbars every one send its progress value and all together create a colore to set as a background to imageview

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    SeekBar seekBar1, seekBar2, seekBar3;
    ImageView imageView;
    public int pro1,pro2,pro3;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        seekBar1 = (SeekBar) this.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        seekBar2 = (SeekBar) this.findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);
        seekBar3 = (SeekBar) this.findViewById(R.id.seekBar3);
        seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
              pro1= progress;
                imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(200, pro1, pro2, pro3));
            }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }
        });
        seekBar2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
               pro2= progress;
                imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(200, pro1, pro2, pro3));
            }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }
        });
        seekBar3.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
               pro3=progress;
                imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(200, pro1, pro2, pro3));
            }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

this youtube
https://youtu.be/AM6lJnze9nA

Comment: Please paste some code to help answer the question instead a link to one of your videos.

Comment: i am so sorry but i am new here